# How to load only javascript file that are needed in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

am using yii2 and all my JS and CSS file are included through the Asset file say SiteAsset.com, but the js file and css file loads to every single page that i loaded on this layout file say main.php layout file, this causes a lot of problem for me as some unwanted code can run on a page where i don't even need it and also delay the time it takes to load, How can I load only css or JS file that are needed for a particular page. some code to illustrate what i mean

```
my asset file 
public $css = [
    //'css/listing.css',    

    '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    '//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css',
    'css/AdminLTE.min.css',
    'css/skins/_all-skins.min.css',
    //'css/skins/skin-custom-1.css',
    //'css/skins/skin-custom-1-light.css',
    'css/skins/_custom-skins.css',
    //'plugins/iCheck/flat/all.css',
    'css/site.css',
    'css/listing.css', 


];
public $js = [


    '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'js/main.js',
    //'plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js',
    '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js',
   '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js',
    'plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js',
   'js/app.min.js',
    //'js/dashboard.js',
    'js/demo.js',
    'js/listing.js',
    'js/functions.js',

];
```

if i have two pages say `index.php` and `welcome.php` and i would like to load `js/listing.js and js/functions.js` in `index.php` but on `welcome.php` page only load `js/functions.js` and not load `js/functions.js` at all. how to achieve this in yii2 any help on this thanks

Comment: I understood. But, this line is quiet confusing -> "*..but on **welcome.php** page only load **js/functions.js** and not load **js/functions.js** at all.*"

Comment: What i mean is on welcome.php file i want to load js/functions.js, and i don't want to laod  js/functions.js  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't have any `module`.

**1)** In your `assets` folder. Create, **AppAsset1.php**.

**AppAsset1.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset1 extends AssetBundle
{
  public $basePath = '@webroot';
  public $baseUrl = '@web';
  public $css = [
    '/app/css/style.css', // Your CSS location
    '/app/css/style1.css',
  ];
  public $js = [
    '/app/js/myscript.js', // Your JS location
    '/app/js/myscript1.js',
  ];

  public $depends = [
    // If you want to keep dependence.
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
  ];
}
```

**2)** Now, In your page where you want to show these *CSS* & *JS*. Include `AppAsset1`.

**MyPage.php**

```
<?php

use app\assets\AppAsset1;
AppAsset1::register($this);

?>
```

Like these, you can create any number of Asset and include wherever you want for that particular page.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but i have module, so with this solution will will override the default asset file for the module, and also this solution is so tedious this will require me create asset file each time i have a page that require different js or css file, any better way to make this work?? thanks

Comment: Show me your module structure. @sam. Don't Say tedious. It's all your requirement. If you have 100 pages and each page require 1 different JS file. So, definitely application will become tedious.

Comment: ok thanks so much maybe i don't have other option left i have to go by doing it one by one,